# Programmatically create ad hoc network with iPhone

Tags: iphone

I Perfectly understand that this is not allowed by the App Store Policy but is programmatically possible to create ad hoc wireless network with the iphone SDK, with "is possible" I mean if the iPhone 3G and/or 3GS hardware support this "feauture" and if exists some kind of low-level api to do this.
This question does NOT contemplate the jailbreak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with the SDK, no. Third-party apps don't get much access to the wireless hardware, and creating networks would definitely be a no-go.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so; however, it's possible that there's something undocumented I'm not aware of.